# bwlabel on enhanced image results in black image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I tried  to enhance an image and perform connected component analysis but it returns a black image.

My code is

```
I = imread('Sub.png');
I=rgb2gray(I);
imshow(I)

J = adapthisteq(I);
imshow(J)
figure, imhist(J,64)
% I = contrast(I);
L = bwlabel(J);
figure,imshow(label2rgb(L,'jet','k','shuffle'));
```

Also how to number each blob after `bwlabel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is only a matter of scaling the intensity of `J` when you call `bwlabel`, since the image is of type uint8. Its maximal possible value is thus 255.

Using this line instead:

```
L = bwlabel(J/255);
```

Outputs the following:

[image]

Yay!